# implementing greater than / less than operator

Tags: java

how do these 2 operators work? been trying to look at how they would be implemented. would it be the same as finding the max and min? im trying to implement > and < in java , but im a little confused on how. i have done the min/max implementations and i think it would be the same. so if i have a list and want all numbers greater then 4. how can i do that?

this is what i was trying to work with

```
public int getMax(ArrayList list){
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i) > max){
            max = list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

Comment: First, you *can't* implement `>` and `<` in Java. They are built-in operators working on numeric primitive values only. [JLS 15.20.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1): *"The type of each of the operands of a numerical comparison operator must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a **primitive numeric type**."* --- Second, your code doesn't compile, because the `ArrayList` is raw *(don't do that!!)*, so `get(i)` is an `Object`, resulting in compile error: *The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't mean to be rude, but I think you should start from the ground up, this is extremely basic.

As for your question, if you have an array of numbers, you would simply need to loop through the array and check them one by one.

As for your question, take this for example:

Case 1: <

```
int a = 1;
int b = 3;
If (a < b) { 
    System.out.println("yay");
} else { 
    System.out.println("AWW man!");
}
```

Since 1 is indeed smaller than 3, then (a < b) is true, which means that "yay" would be printed in the console.

Case 2: >

```
int a = 1;
int b = 3;
If (a > b) { 
    System.out.println("yay");
} else { 
    System.out.println("AWW man!");
}
```

Since 1 is NOT greater than 3, then (a > b) returns false, which means that "Aww man!" would be printed in the console.

Now that we have this established, to find the smallest number in an array, this is what we should do:

```
int[] myList = {6, 2, 9, 40, 1};
int lowestNum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i<myList.length; i++) {
    if (lowestNum > myList[i]) {
        lowestNum = myList[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks alot , i dont know why i couldnt figure this out. i appreciate it

Comment: Pleasure's mine :)